# How do I draw a vector shape in Flutter?

Tags: android, vector, flutter

We are trying to build a custom shape vector in Flutter that can be changed at runtime.

For example, we need a pizza shape vector widget that we can change the slice color base on a variable value.

We tried to use the canvas and painter in Flutter but they don't have a clear and good doc.

We tried SVG too but unfortunately Flutter doesn't support SVG tag and SVG view too.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a widget that extends [CustomPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html)

> ```
> class Sky extends CustomPainter {
>   @override
>   void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
>     var rect = Offset.zero & size;
>     var gradient = new RadialGradient(
>       center: const Alignment(0.7, -0.6),
>       radius: 0.2,
>       colors: [const Color(0xFFFFFF00), const Color(0xFF0099FF)],
>       stops: [0.4, 1.0],
>     );
>     canvas.drawRect(
>       rect,
>       new Paint()..shader = gradient.createShader(rect),
>     );
>   }
>
>   @override
>   SemanticsBuilderCallback get semanticsBuilder {
>     return (Size size) {
>       // Annotate a rectangle containing the picture of the sun
>       // with the label "Sun". When text to speech feature is enabled on the
>       // device, a user will be able to locate the sun on this picture by
>       // touch.
>       var rect = Offset.zero & size;
>       var width = size.shortestSide * 0.4;
>       rect = const Alignment(0.8, -0.9).inscribe(new Size(width, width), rect);
>       return [
>         new CustomPainterSemantics(
>           rect: rect,
>           properties: new SemanticsProperties(
>             label: 'Sun',
>             textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
>           ),
>         ),
>       ];
>     };
>   }
>
>   // Since this Sky painter has no fields, it always paints
>   // the same thing and semantics information is the same.
>   // Therefore we return false here. If we had fields (set
>   // from the constructor) then we would return true if any
>   // of them differed from the same fields on the oldDelegate.
>   @override
>   bool shouldRepaint(Sky oldDelegate) => false;
>   @override
>   bool shouldRebuildSemantics(Sky oldDelegate) => false;
> }
> ```

See also

- https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_svg (limited SVG support for Flutter)
- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/dev/tools/vitool
- https://github.com/simolus3/fluttie (not sure this is working already)